# Are the lifecycle methods a design pattern of its own, or is it a more general class of design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Today I saw that React (React JS) has lifecycle methods, such as

```
componentWillMount()
```

and so when the component or container is instantiated for the first time, this method will be called if it exists. (if it is defined).

One example of it is, when the component is instantiated for the first time, if the above method `componentWillMount()` is defined in the class, then it will be called, and it may do an AJAX call to fetch data to populate into this component.

And the same is true for iOS or Cocoa programming:

```
viewDidLoad()
viewWillAppear()
```

and this type of "if it exists (or is defined), then call it" actually was similar to the old days of

```
document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function() { };
```

That is, if `onclick` is defined, then call it. Otherwise, just ignore it. But this is related more to event handling / observer pattern / chain of responsibility, more than lifecycle methods.

(Having said, actually, you can also view lifecycle methods as event handlers too: such as, now the View or Component will be shown, I (the OS or the framework) am telling you / notifying you (about this event): if you need to do something, do it now (handle it now)).

The question is: do these lifecycle methods `componentWillMount()`, `viewWillApear()` a design pattern of its own, or do they belong to a bigger class or more general class of design pattern?

Comment: They're just boolean functions.  They're used all the time when you want to retrieve some sort of status.  It doesn't seem to me that using them in this particular context affords them any special status.

Comment: no, AFAIK, they DO something. Such as, in `componentWillMount()`, the programmer can do AJAX call to fetch data particular to that component

Comment: You mean they have side effects?  Boo.

Comment: @RobertHarvey actually, these aren't boolran, they're event handler functions.

Comment: Then why are they named like boolean functions?

Comment: Yeah, I was right; they're boolean functions.  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621423-viewdidappear).  Though it says that "You can override this method to perform additional tasks associated with presenting the view," can I be the first to say "yuck?"

Comment: http://matteomanferdini.com/the-common-lifecycle-of-a-view-controller/

Comment: Ah, sorry.  It *is* an event handler.  The method naming there is quite unfortunate, though I suppose if you're familiar with this architecture it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The answer to your question is that this method is part of the ViewController architecture.  I don't know much about Apple/cocoa mechanics, but I suspect that it is some variation on MVC or MVVM, so there's your overarching pattern.

Comment: And if you're thinking "he doesn't get it," to that I say "not everything is a well-known software pattern."  Event handlers are a well-known pattern.  MVC is a well-known pattern.  The life-cycle of a ViewController in UIKIT is, I suppose, a well-known pattern, simply by virtue of it being Apple software used by thousands of developers all over the world, so Apple's documentation already describes the software patterns you're looking for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey for me the viewDidLoad was a pretty poor name for probably something like viewLoaded/viewLoadedFinished. However i recognized the event handler. Maybe not that fast if it wouldn't have been something else than Javascript.

Comment: I feel like I'm making up patterns now, but this looks kind of like a hook pattern: http://stevenblack.com/articles/hook-operations/.   Though at the same time, the react hook doesn't look like it should be used by mere mortals: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: @RobertHarvey  I think your understanding of English is slightly different.  `willViewAppear()` should return a Boolean. It is asking "will this view appear, yes or no?"  But `viewWillAppear()` is different, it's _telling you_ this view is about to appear.  Methods like this usually pass in a context object or just the view and allow you to modify or set up something in preparation for what is about to happen.  It's a very important pattern, sometimes called **delegation** and one that I happen to think is very handy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey also here's a link to a doc about delegation in Cocoa: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Comment: @RibaldEddie: It's a poorly-named event handler.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I quite like it-- and the pattern in general.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in native Javascript you have already plenty of events handler :

- onShow
- onClick
- onFocus
- ...

These are just the same principle wrapped in the framework, and they added some their own.

For me it's not a specific pattern, it's just how Javascript (and even UI) usually works : event based.

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that this is an instance of [pipe-and-filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters) architectural pattern. Usually it is used to process data through multiple steps and the output of each step is an input to another.

Although, this does not fit the provided description, since no explicit data is passed between the steps (in this case the functions), there is clearly a correlation between the functions - one does not start before the previous is finished. Additionally, the manual changes from each function/process can be seen as implicit data filtering, and the current (updated) context can be considered as the passed data to the next process/function.

It is a quite common naturally occurring pattern, so you can find it in many places. Considering this, I don't think it as important as understanding the different processes that happen in the chain and in which cases they are executed/skipped.